# any fuction in python as polyeig() in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, scientific-computing, eigenvalue

i'm trying to solve a polynomial eigen value problem in python and i need a function like polyeig in matlab, is there any library that is capable of doing this?

The problem that i'm trying to solve is of the form

`c0+c1*alpha+c2*alpha**2+c3*alpha**3=0`

where c is a matrix and alpha the eigen values of the given problem.

Comment: Have you checked scipy's [eigenvalue problem functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html#eigenvalue-problems)?

Comment: yes, but untill now, nothing alike, there is this library called lapack that seem to be a way to do it, but no idea how to code or get at least an example. @PedroRodrigues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the polynomial eigenvalue in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252428/how-to-solve-the-polynomial-eigenvalue-in-python)

Comment: I've posted a `polyeig` implementation [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65516134/627911).